# How to solve $Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0$ if $x_{1,2} = x_0 \pm \sqrt{R^2 - (y - y_0)^2}$?

Tags: systems-of-equations, circles, conic-sections, quartics

I'm trying to find the intersection points of circle and conic section curve. So, I'm solving the system of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0 \\
(x - x_0)^2 + (y - y_0)^2 = R^2
\end{cases}
$$

From the second equation I can find that $x = x_0 \pm \sqrt{R^2 - (y - y_0)^2}$

Then I put it to the first equation and getting coefficients of quartic equation $ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e = 0$ which must give me the $y$ roots:

Substitutions for simplicity:

$
\alpha = 2Ax_0 + D \\
\beta = A - C \\
\gamma = -(2Ay_0 + Bx_0 + E) \\
\delta = A(y_0^2 - x_0^2 - R^2) - Dx_0 - F \\
\epsilon = R^2 - y_0^2$

Coefficients of quartic equation:

$
a = \beta^2 + B^2 \\
b = 2(\beta\gamma + B\alpha - B^2y_0) \\
c = 2\beta\delta + \gamma^2 - B^2\epsilon + \alpha^2 - 4B\alpha y_0 \\
d = 2(\gamma\delta - B\alpha\epsilon - \alpha^2y_0) \\
e = \delta^2 - \alpha^2\epsilon
$

In most cases the solving of this equation gives me a two real and two complex roots. I skip the complex roots and put the real into the equation of x. But it leads me to the complex x roots.

Did I made mistake in my calculations of a,b,c,d,e of quartic equation? Or am I trying to solve it in the wrong way?

I tried to solve it few times and got the same coefficients each time.

Comment: There will be no real solutions when the two conic sections do not intersect. Try your code on a simple case where you know that they *do* intersect and compare the numbers step by step.

Comment: @dxiv I made an app that visualise ellipse and circle and points. And points are wrong

Comment: Then step through the code and see where the numbers diverge from what you get on paper. This sounds like a matter of programming and debugging, rather than math.

Comment: @dxiv I think, the problem in my calculations. There is high probability of mistake.

Comment: @dxiv I put the roots into the conic sections equation and result is not 0. There is error in my calculations but I can't find it

Comment: When I put x into the conic section equation I got a square root at one side of equation and non-root at second side. Then I raise both sides to square and got the quartic equation. Is this way valid?
The given y root is valid for quartic equation but not valid for conic equation

Comment: That is one way to eliminate a variable between the equations. You probably have an error in the calculations, which would be easier to point out if you posted a simple numeric example where it fails.

Comment: @dxiv For i.e. ellipse with $a = 150, b = 90$ ($a, b$ parallel to $x, y$, center is $(0; 0)$) and circle with radius $100$ at center $(50;50)$

If I put found roots into conic section equation I don't get $0$.

Conic section equation in my case:
$A = 1/a^2 \\ B = 0 \\ C = 1/b^2 \\ D = 0 \\ E = 0 \\ F = -1$

Comment: @dxiv Damned. I found that I used $b$ instead of $B$ when calculated $d$. Maybe it is the root of evil, need to recheck results

Comment: Now it is working for the given example, but not working if circle center is (0;50)

Comment: It's because imaginary part of roots is not $0$ and I'm skipping it. And if circle center is (0;0) and ellipse b is 100, then imaginary part goes much bigger. Maybe problem in floating point computations on PC